# I can't do anything with python dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop

Im really stuck with a little problem that I have.

```
diccionario_antiguos = {}
            
    data = open('Currency_price.json')
    for i in data:
        diccionario_antiguos = i
```

Currency_price.json is a file which contains a dictionary like this:

```
{"Dolar": ["80,25", "86,25"], "Euro": ["96,59", "97,04"]}
```

With the key being the currency and the value a list with its prices.

My problem is that after I pass all the info to diccionario_antiguos, I can't manipulate anything inside it.

if i do for instance:

```
print(diccionario_antiguos.get('Dolar')
```

I get 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

If I do

```
print(diccionario_antiguos['Dolar']
```

I get string indices must be integers

And then I said "Oh, I should have tu use integers", so I did:

```
print(diccionario_antiguos[0])
```

No Exception there, but I get [] (when I printed the whole dictionary and I KNOW the data IS there).

I don't know what's happening, because if I apply this methods with any dictionary, they'll work, even if the key is a String.

Any solutions? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Why are you looping? Why are you assigning `diccionario_antiguos = i`? Why does this code not even involve a JSON parser?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Im assigning diccionario_antiguos = i as it's the only why I know to get the dict data, and it works, is there a better way? And, what exactly is a json parser? Thank you for answering!

Comment: @Prune I just did the following test: diccionario_antiguos = {'Hola':123.4} print(diccionario_antiguos['Hola']) data = open('Currency_price.json') for i in data: diccionario_antiguos = i print(diccionario_antiguos['Dolar']) Sorry for the mess... As you can see, the first dict works perfectly, while the second, which is the same structure, does not. I want to know why, because I don't see a reason. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Again, update your *question* with working code -- as you can see, a comment does *not* represent code properly.  Also note that we do *not* have your JSON file.  Unless you have isolated the problem to loading, you should remove the reading from your post, and simply hard-code a few sample lines in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code for json and dict...

```
import json
j = '''{"Dolar": ["80,25", "86,25"], "Euro": ["96,59", "97,04"]} '''
jDict = json.loads(j)
print(jDict)
print("Dolar List", jDict['Dolar'])
print("Euro  List", jDict['Euro'])

# Write Dict to json file
fn = 'Currency_price.json'
with open(fn, 'w') as fio:
    json.dump(jDict, fio)

# Read Json file
with open(fn, 'r') as fio:
    j2Dict = json.load(fio)

print("\n-------\n")

print(j2Dict)
print("Dolar List", j2Dict['Dolar'])
print("Euro  List", j2Dict['Euro'])
```

output

```
{'Dolar': ['80,25', '86,25'], 'Euro': ['96,59', '97,04']}
Dolar List ['80,25', '86,25']
Euro  List ['96,59', '97,04']

-------

{'Dolar': ['80,25', '86,25'], 'Euro': ['96,59', '97,04']}
Dolar List ['80,25', '86,25']
Euro  List ['96,59', '97,04']
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, so it had something to do with the way I was opening the json file, thank you!